# Compose `Icons.Outlined.Star` isn't outlined

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I am creating an app in Compose with a really simple navigation bar which displays two items: home and starred:

```
@Composable
fun HomeScreen(modifier: Modifier) {
    var selectedItem by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }

    val items = listOf(
        stringResource(id = R.string.bottomNavigationMenu_home),
        stringResource(id = R.string.bottomNavigationMenu_starred)
    )

    val icons = listOf(
        Icons.Outlined.Home,
        Icons.Outlined.Star,
    )

    Box(
        modifier = modifier
    ) {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Bottom
        ) {
            NewProjectButton(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(16.dp)
                    .align(Alignment.End)
            )

            NavigationBar {
                items.forEachIndexed { index, item ->
                    NavigationBarItem(
                        icon = {
                            Icon(icons[index], contentDescription = item) },
                        label = {
                            Text(item)
                        },
                        selected = selectedItem == index,
                        onClick = { selectedItem = index }
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The output looks like so (I have to embed the link as StackOverflow gives me an error when I try to do otherwise):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Zjxw.png

As you can probably see from the image, the star is not outlined and instead is filled. I was wondering whether or not this is fixable or it is an internal bug.

### Edit 1

This seems to be an internal bug within Compose, whether or not it has been fixed on a newer version I don't know, but I am using the latest release candidate, so it's unlikely. I have filed an issue request to Google here: https://issuetracker.google.com/u/1/issues/253388323

Comment: go to this site and search for your icon and see if that icon supports outlined or not https://fonts.google.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the star outline shape is not available on material standard icons but you have the option of using the extended icons libs `androidx.compose.material:material-icons-extended` dependency which contains the full set of Material icons.

However, this is not encouraged due to the large size of this library. This leaves you with the option of using [Android Studio's Import vector asset](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/icons/package-summary). feature.

For this you can follow these steps **Right Click on Drawable Folder** -> **New** -> **Vector Asset** -> **Select Clip Art Radio Button** -> **Click on Clip Art Button** -> *search for 'Star Outline' on the search box* -> **Next** -> **Finish**. Follow the same steps to import another vector for the home icon.

Thereafter you can create a list of painterResource as shown below.

```
val icons = listOf(
            painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_outline_star),
            painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_empty_home)
    )
```

After that you can use the same code for the icons at an index.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a bug. Outlined version of Star is also filled, you can use  Icons.Outlined.StarRate.

I tried to upload showing stars but there is a server error with stackoverflow at the moment.

You can check out by selecting `File>New>Vector Asset` and typing `star` and selecting Outlined to see each version.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Icons.Outlined.StarOutline`